Angular + API + backend Node
I have an Angular application and I need it to send an API POST request, but this request would have to be executed outside the browser, that is, through the node backend or through Powershell or through linux... Has anyone ever needed to perform this operation or know if it would be possible?
I tried to execute the requests but everything I tried was unsuccessful.

"Angular application and I need it to send an API POST request, but this request would have to be executed outside the browser, that is, through the node backend or through powershell or through linux" - what is the meaning of this? "need it to send" means that the application sends a request from the environment where it's evaluated, i.e. a browser

It sounds like you can wrangle something together using a tool like puppeteer or cypress but that's still within a browser context, just executable from a script.

An "Angular app" runs within the browser, so the only way it can send request is within the browser's context. And for very good reasons, it doesn't have access to the OS's resources like powershell or similar ...

you'd need to have a server perform that request.  You should probably explain more about what you are trying to do.
